# Array.push makes all objects the same

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a `cart.service` in my Angular app which manage the items added to a cart from a list.

To each item i can add some variants so it's object will change, but when i'm adding the same item twice with two different variants it will change the first `pushed` object to the same as the last added.

Like i'm adding to cart `{ id: 1, variants: [{ 2 }] }` and second item `{ id: 1, variants: [{ 3 }] }` the array will be `[ { id: 1, variants: [{ 3 }] }, { id: 1, variants: [{ 3 } }]`

The method where i'm adding to the item object variants is `(change)` on checkbox where i'm passing the item object and doing the following

```
  checkVariante(variante: Varianti, event: any, plu: Plu): void {
      if (event.target.checked) {
        variante.stato = 'PIU';
        plu.varianti.push(variante); // adding variant to item object
      } else {
        const index = plu.varianti.indexOf(variante); // removing variant from item object
        if (index !== -1) {
          plu.varianti.splice(index, 1);
        }
  }
```

And then i'm adding it to cart with the cart.service as the following:

```
  addToCart(plu: Plu): void {
    this.cartService.addToCart(plu);
  }

cart.service

  addToCart(product: Plu): any{
    product.qta = 1;
    this.carrello.plu.push(product);
  }
```

But if after adding the first item i refresh the page and then add the same item with other variants all will be added to the cart correctly... it seems that when i'm adding variants to the item i'm changing the current item object.. but how can i solve it?

Comment: You have a single `variante` object you change a value of then push. You need *new* objects if you don't want the same object.

Comment: @DaveNewton yea actually solved by using `Object.assign()` and by changing the cloned object instead of the original one